# What is this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to run the following code but I KEEP GETTING THE ERROR. I also tried adding document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => but it is still not working. It dosn't give me error if I put the code inside console. It also doesn't give me error when I load it for the first time. But as soon as I refresh it starts giving me errors.

```
import './Slider.css';
import Acc from './Accomodation/Acc'
import Flora from './Flora/Flora'
import Food from './OurFood/Food.js'
import Trek from './Treks/Treks';
import View from './OurView/View';
import Indoor from './IndoorGames/games';
let slideIndex = 0;
SlideShow()

function SlideShow(){
    
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")
  console.log(slides)
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  slideIndex++;
  console.log(slideIndex)
  console.log(slides)
  if (slideIndex === 0) {slideIndex = 1}
  else if (slideIndex === slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  else if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  console.log(slides[slideIndex])
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 

  setTimeout(SlideShow, 10000);

}

function Slider() {


    return (
    <div className='Slider'>
        <h1>Experiences</h1>
        <hr />
        <div className='MySlides'>
        <div className='1 slide fade'>
        <Acc></Acc>
        </div>
        <div className='2 slide fade'>
        <Flora></Flora>
        </div>
        <div className='3 slide fade'>
        <Food></Food>
        </div>
        <div className='4 slide fade'>
        <Trek></Trek>
        </div>
        <div className='5 slide fade'>
        <View></View>
        </div>
        <div className='6 slide fade'>
        <Indoor></Indoor>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    
    )  

    
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full error message as well as the messages printed in the log.  Better yet, include a minimal reproducible example.  As it stands, where are the 'slide' classes in your document?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Fundamentally, your code is assuming there will always be at least one element in `slides` with this statement: `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` (where `slideIndex` seems to always be `1` or higher). But if there are no elements with that class, there won't be any elements in `slides`, and `slides[slideIndex-1]` will be `slides[0]` which will be `undefined`.

Comment: Separately, if you're using React, you shouldn't be directly manipulating the DOM like that. Instead, maintain the slide state in your component, and update the state. React will reconcile that update with the DOM. (Or of course, just don't use React and work directly with the DOM.)

Answer (score 0):

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

According to the error message, your code is trying to call the `style` property; but **a specific object** doesn't have the `style` property. What do I mean by *a specific object*? An example:

```
const someObject = { // the object
 style: 'some value' // the property
}
```

So, we need to look at the references of `style` in your code, and locate the specific parent objects in your code:

1. `slides[i].style.display = "none";` -> the parent object is `slides[i]`
2. `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` -> the parent object is `slides[slideIndex-1]`

So, `slides[i]` or `slides[slideIndex-1]` objects don't have the `style` property.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```js
try {} 
catch (error) {console.log(error)}
```

It will log the error

And the main problem is `slides[slideIndex-1]` does not have values so that it can not read `styles` property